# Appending results in vue.js to semantic UI based Template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working to add "LOAD MORE" which would load more random products in the current page. My problem is that it is not appending but instead it is changing the current value on which the user will click "LOAD MORE". How do I append value without changing the previous value when clicked on "LOAD MORE".

```
<div class="ui six doubling cards" id="app-5">
      <div class="card" v-for="i in message">
        <div class="image">
          <img v-bind:src="[[ i.ImageURL ]]">
          <div class="ui top right attached red label">[[i.OfferPercentage]]% OFF</div>

        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <a v-bind:href="[[i.ProductURL]]" target="_blank">
            <div class="ui container">
              <div class="ui tiny blue header"> [[i.ProductName]]</div>
              <h5 class="ui grey header">[[i.Category]]</h5>
              <h5 class="ui red header">₹[[i.ActualPrice]] <s>₹[[i.StrikedPrice]]</s> </h5>

            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button v-on:click="reverseMessage" class="fluid ui button">Load More</button>

    </div>
    <p></p>


<script>
    var app5 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-5',
    delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
    data: {
        message: []
    },
    methods: {
        reverseMessage: function () {
          axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test').then(response => {
            this.message = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: how do you generate that data?

Comment: Generate Data ? @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: i mean random products

Comment: I am loading random products by exposing the API made in Flask and using MongoDB as the database. I am using the MongoDB Aggregate sample function to load data --> mob = db.Products.aggregate([{'$sample': {'size': 60}}]). So whenever you hit "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test". I will give you random products. @BoussadjraBrahim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing `this.message`, append to it:

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test').then(response => {
    this.message.push(...response.data);
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked. Thank you very much @jotaelesalinas. BTW is there any security risk ?

Comment: I don't see any security risk. But remember that you have to check for failures with `.catch()`.